# How stop wrong mobile app from pairing with Bluetooth device?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create an mobile app to pair with a Bluetooth device. However, I do not want any other app to pair with this bluetooth device. What is the best solution to prevent this?

I tried to think of an passcode the mobile app can send to the device. If this is the right solution, does the mobile app send the passcode to the device during pairing or discovery or.. ?

Comment: Please read some informations about BLE: https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/ Pairing is the process of sharing encryption keys. You will not have any influence on the keys, you can only use different pairing methods. There are methods that require a passcode, but this depends on your BLE device and whether you have full control over it

Comment: Do you have access to the source code /program of the remote Bluetooth device? If not, then you will not be able to prevent other devices pairing with it.